# MySQL замена выбранных данных в выборке select

Tags: mysql, select, if

Добрый день! Запрос вытаскивает из таблицы строки с IDшниками, например

```
Select id, dat from table1;

id               dat
55123213        s
53244351        d
55100000        e
```

Вместо id Нужно в итоге написать текст (логин пользователя, который в других таблицах не используется нигде, то есть определим его вручную). Как это можно сделать, чтобы на выходе уже заменялись данные?

Comment: Через конструкцию `case`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо действительно использовать case, либо всё же завести еще одно поле в таблице.

**Первый вариант**:

```
SELECT
    CASE `id`
        WHEN 55123213 THEN 'Вася Пупкин'
        WHEN 53244351 THEN 'Невася Пупкин'
        WHEN 55100000 THEN 'Вася Непупкин'
    END as `user_name`,
    `dat`
FROM `table1`
```

**Второй вариант**.

Сначала делаете один раз:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD COLUMN `user_name` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL;
```

Потом выполняете запрос уже так:

```
SELECT `user_name`, `dat` FROM `table1`
```

Comment: Спасибо всем, именно через Case пришлось сделать, т.к. нет доступа полного к таблице :)

Answer (score 0):

Запрос будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
Select case id when 55123213 then 'login1'
when 53244351 then 'login2'
when 55100000 then 'login3' end ID, dat
from table1
```